# firebase observeeventtype jsqmessagecollectionview avatar

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm going to show avatar image of users within a conversation. I used JSQMessageViewController, so the function below should be used to achieve this goal. However, observeeventtype seems like get out this function and not being called, and there is a nil(MyuserImage or OtheruserImage) in return. So crash will appear. So how can I get photo url of different users in firebase and then return the expected avatar image? Thank you!

```
    - (id<JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JSQMessage *message = [self.msgArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    if([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]){
        NSString *MyuserId = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;
        __block NSString *MyuserImage;
        NSLog(@"uid is : %@",MyuserId);
        [[_photoRef child:@"users"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
            NSLog(@"My key is : %@",snapshot.key);
            if([snapshot.key isEqualToString:MyuserId]){
                NSLog(@"snapshot value is : %@", snapshot.value);
                MyuserImage = snapshot.value[@"photo"];
            }
        }];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:MyuserImage];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        self.myuserImage= [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        return [JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory avatarImageWithImage:self.myuserImage diameter:15];
    }
    else{
        NSString *OtheruserId = message.senderId;
        __block NSString *OtheruserImage;
        NSLog(@"other userId is: %@",OtheruserId);
        [[_photoRef child:@"users"]observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
            NSLog(@"other user's key is: %@", snapshot.key);
            if([snapshot.key isEqualToString:OtheruserId]){
                NSLog(@"snapshot value is: %@", snapshot.value);
                OtheruserImage = snapshot.value[@"photo"];
            }
        }];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:OtheruserImage];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        self.otheruserImage= [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        return [JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory avatarImageWithImage:self.otheruserImage diameter:15];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From best I can tell it looks like you need to be pulling this data from firebase before this method gets called. Something like creating a struct that matches your data structure and then being able to pull this information from your datasource which presumably would be an array of these structs you've created.

An implementation I'd also recommend exploring is to use a library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which will manage the async call for you and let you set a default avatar while the network request and image rendering happen. But still you will need that url fetched from your database before this method gets called.